# KerasClassifier for use with build_fn which takes arguments

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, keras, deep-learning

I am attempting to wrap my keras models in scikit learn [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) and [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) structures for hyperparameter tuning.

It works absolutely fine when the `build_fn` function takes 0 arguments for use in `KerasClassifier`. However it fails whenever I use a function which takes arguments.

Example code below

```py
def prepare_classifier(x, y):

    shape_of_input = x.shape
    shape_of_target = y.shape

    classifier  = Sequential()

    ## number of neurons = 30
    ## kernel_initializer determines how the weights are initialized
    ## activation is the activation function at this particular hidden layer
    ## input_shape is the number of features in a single row.. in this case it is shape_of_input[1]
    ## shape_of_input[0] is the total number of such rows
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 30, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'uniform', input_dim = shape_of_input[1]))

    classifier.add(Dense(units = 30, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))

    ## we are predicting 10 digits for each row of x.
    ## in total there are shape_of_input[0] rows in total
    classifier.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

    ## categorical_crossentropy is the loss function for multi output loss function
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return classifier



def fit(classifier, x_train, y_train, epoch_size, batch_size = 10):
    pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('keras_classifier', classifier)
    ])
    param_grid = {
        'keras_classifier__batch_size' : [10,20,30,50],
        'keras_classifier__epochs' : [100, 200, 300],
        'keras_classifier__x' : [x_train],
        'keras_classifier__y' : [y_train],
    }

    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipeline, param_grid = param_grid, n_jobs = -1)
    grid.fit(x_train, y_train)

    print("Best parameters are : ", grid.best_params_, '\n grid best score :', grid.best_score_)


classifier =  KerasClassifier(build_fn = prepare_classifier, x = x_train[0:100], y = y_train )

fit(classifier, x_train[:100], y_train, epoch_size )
```

This is for some x, and some y data (p.s. I have used mnist data)

The error I get is :

RuntimeError: Cannot clone object , as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter x

However if my `prepare_classifier` function takes no arguments code works absolutely fine.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Set default values of `x` and `y` in `prepare_classifier`

Comment: No. this cannot be done. this doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

solved it. essentially the below line was the issue

```
classifier =  KerasClassifier(build_fn = prepare_classifier, x = x_train[0:100], y = y_train )
```

needed to be changed to

```
classifier =  KerasClassifier(build_fn = prepare_classifier)
```

and the parameters for the prepare_classifier needs to be sent using param_grid